# Convert Row_Number() function from SQL Server to sqlite

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I am converting my SQL Server database to sqlite. I have a stored procedure in which `Row_Number()` function is used. How to write the following query of SQL Server in sqlite as `Row_Number()` cannot be used in sqlite. Any alternative?

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         tblDomains.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tblDomains.DomainName ASC) AS rowNum
     FROM
         tblDomains
     WHERE 
         (1=1) AND (IsDeleted = 'False')
         AND (DomainName LIKE '%hostingcontroller.com%')) AS q
WHERE 
    q.rowNum > 0 AND q.rowNum < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite supports `row_number()`, but you can phrase this as:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM tblDomains d 
WHERE d.IsDeleted = 'False' AND
      d.DomainName LIKE '%hostingcontroller.com%'
ORDER BY d.DomainName ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

In SQL Server, you would replace `LIMIT 1` with `SELECT TOP (1)`.

Comment: LIMIT will not work in my case because i am doing pagination according to given 2 upper and lower dynamic parameters.

Comment: @SharjeelMalik . . . (1) This answers the question that you asked.  (2) If you are doing paging, you should be using `limit`/`offset`.  So the answer is essentially the same.